# How would I create this index in Neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, graph-databases, titan

In Titan, I create an index using:

```
graph.makeKey("name").dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).indexed(Edge.class).unique().make();
```

How can I do this in Neo4j using the Java API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Cypher you would create a label based constraint on the label `:Person` and the property `name` like this.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (p:Person) ASSERT p.name IS UNIQUE;
```

In the Java API it is

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {      
  db.schema().constraintFor(DynamicLabel.label("Person")).assertPropertyIsUnique("name").create();
  tx.success();
}
```

Comment: I'm using the Blueprints implementation of Neo4j and GraphDatabaseService doesn't have the ```schema()``` method, is there a Blueprints implementation of Neo4j2? Or do I need to do something else to retrieve the ```Schema```?